# How can I best dynamically populate dropdowns in a flask app?

Tags: javascript, flask, javascript-objects

I am inheriting a project that includes a section of code like this:

```
    {% for device in test.devices.devices %}
        <tr id="{{ outer_loop.index }}.{{ loop.index }}.device-row">
            <th scope="col">{{ loop.index }}</th>
            <td>
                <select class="device-platform-name-selector" name="{{ outer_loop.index }}.{{ loop.index }}.platform_name">
                {% for current_platform_name_option in test.device_platform_name_options %}
                    <option
                            value="{{ current_platform_name_option }}"
                            {% if current_platform_name_option == device.platform_name %} selected {% endif %}>
                        {{ current_platform_name_option }}
                    </option>
                {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
```

followed by a series of input fields.

My task is to change this into a series of dropdown dialogs that react to the previously-set fields (based on a dictionary, from a database table, passed to the render_template). I need to assign these `<option>` fields both (a) when the page first is populated, and (b) every time any of the dropdowns change their selection. (I also need to handle adding a new entry, but that code is already present and should be straightforward once I figure out the following questions.)

I am new to Javascript and Flask so some of my questions might be idiotic, and I apologize:

1. Is putting a javascript `onLoad()` event on each of the subsequent `<select>` fields the correct technique for initially populating the `<option>` fields for those `<select>`s? Or should I be populating this option list data back in python and pushing it via template parameters? (The initialization is complicated by the fact that the number of items in the device `loop` and number of items in the `outer_loop` can vary. Also, pre-set values coming from flask are supposed to affect the initially selected `<option>` in all of the dropdowns.)
2. Would it be a best-practice to create variables that represent the selections made in the page (ala model-view-ish), or is it normal to refer to the HTML element selections as the true source of information for these sorts of operations?
3. If it is best-practice to use variables, can I re-use the variables passed via Jinja/templates in a live fashion, or do I need to re-create all such variables ala `var myfoo = JSON.parse('{{ foo | tojson | safe }}');`. (PS: I'm not asking if changes to foo would be propagated back to the server, just whether I can alter `foo` locally.)
4. If it is normal and OK to use HTML elements as the 'model', then how can I, within an onLoad() or onChange() event, navigate my way from the handled `this` object to get back to the values from the "master" parent and sibling objects that determine what the current options will be? Can I parse the current object's `name` to determine the relevant `outer_loop.index` and `loop.index` pieces, then access the other elements by name? Or should I "walk up" the HTML/DOM tree?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to follow up on my post

1. It turns out that putting an onLoad() on any of the relevant tags I was considering would not work, since onLoad() is only supported for the body, IMG tags, or SCRIPT tags. There are some ways to get around this, by, for example, jamming in some SCRIPT tags in places where they might not otherwise naturally be, but that seemed like an ugly kludge. I eventually decided to populate the SELECT boxes in the python via the templates for their initial state and pass in the OPTION data via render_template().
2. After looking around other StackOverflow questions, I decided that accessing DOM element values like this `document.getElementById(foo).value;` was common practice; and that making duplicate variables and trying to track their value changing was over-engineering. There probably are frameworks that would have made doing so natural and easy, but I did not want to ramp up on any new frameworks.
3. I'm almost certain the `{{ variable }}` style Jinja variables are read only. I couldn't find any examples of people trying to use them otherwise, but several examples of people loading them into local variables within their javascript.
4. The answer to this was "both". Navigating to sibling and parent objects was fairly straight forward. I already had template loops to load the page initially that assigned unique ids to each element, so it was easy to fetch indexes of elements, something like `var newIndex = element.id.split(".")[1]` then rebuild the names and find the corresponding element like `document.getElementById("sibling_thing." + newIndex)`. But I also made use of what I referred to above as "DOM walks", for example: `element.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll(foo)`. It seems both styles are common practice, and it's on the programmer to use the right tool for the job.